# Space between navigation bar and header?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make a web tutorials page just to help out my skills and I cannot seem to figure out why there is a space between the bottom of my navigation bar and the top of my first header? If anyone could possibly tell me what I wrote that would separate these two that would be amazing!

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #cccccc;
}
.nav ul{
 list-style: none;
 background-color: #444444;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.nav li{
 font-family: 'Oswald'. sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 line-height: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #888888;
 
}
.nav a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
}
.nav a:hover{
 background-color: #005f5f;
 transition: .3s background-color;
}
.nav a.active{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #444444;
 cursor: default;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
 .nav li{
  width: 120px;
  border-bottom: none;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
 }
}
.header{
 background-color: blue;
 height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Responsive design -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Web Tutorials - Making web development easier!</title>

    <!-- Custom Css -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a class="active" href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="tutorials"><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 <div class="header">
  <h1>Welcome to Web Tuts</h1>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `h1` element has a default margin set by the user agent stylesheet of the browser.

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>Welcome to Web Tuts</h1>
</div>
```

You have to remove this margin.

```
.header h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Obligatory [CSS reset link](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #cccccc;
}
.header h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald'. sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888888;
}
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #444444;
  cursor: default;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
}
.header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Responsive design -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Web Tutorials - Making web development easier!</title>

  <!-- Custom Css -->
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="home"><a class="active" href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tutorials"><a href="#">HTML</a>
      </li>
      <li class="about"><a href="#">CSS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="contact"><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Welcome to Web Tuts</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix that tiny issue is easy, to use a global reset framework is probably easy too. What I would suggest, you should study the basic default browser stylesheet rules, that will bring you CSS skills to the next level.

You can basically go and read through all the lines:

Mozilla Firefox etc
http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/layout/style/html.css

Apple Safari etc http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css

They are quite similar, I suggest to read Mozilla's first. We don't have to remember all of them, just the most common ones will be enough, such as the heading, paragraph, list and blockquote etc.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
h1
{
margin:0;
}
```

there is auto margin in `h1` tag which you need to make it 0

Answer (score 0):

Hope the above solved the issue.

Just wanted to follow up to ask if you're comfortable using the web inspector tools.

Sometimes you can try a million things with no luck, but inspect the area and it jumps right out. Troubleshooting issues like this is so much easier to do in the inspector.

I really like the ones built into Chrome, but everyone has a preference.

[This](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/mastering-developer-tools-console) article on TeamTreehouse.com blog is a pretty good intro!